# Issue with Alamofire challenge delegate and escaping closure

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am using AF and using it's delegate to catch the authentication challenge returned by my server.

```
func connectGetRequest(_ url : URL){

    let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    sessionManager.request(url).responseString { response in
        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
    }
    let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = sessionManager.delegate
    
    
    delegate.taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion = { session, task, challenge,  completionHander in
        print("session is \(session), task is \(task) challenge is \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod) and handler is \(completionHander)")
        if(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == "NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust"){

            completionHander(.performDefaultHandling,nil)
        }else{
            
            print("challenge type is \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")
            
      // Following line give me the error: "passing non-escaping parameter 'completionHander' to function expecting an @escaping closure"

self.handleAuthenticationforSession(challenge,completionHandler:  completionHander)
        }
    }
    
    delegate.dataTaskDidReceiveData = {session , task, data in
        
        print("received data \(data)")
    }
    
}


func handleAuthenticationforSession(_ challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,completionHandler:   @escaping (Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    
         
        Authhandler.handleChallenge(forURLSessionChallenge: challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        

}
```

issue I have:

1. If I use the code above as it is, I get

   error: "passing non-escaping  parameter 'completionHander' to function expecting an @escaping closure"
2. If I make the parameter of the function handleAuthenticationSession non escaping, I get :

   ```
    func handleAuthenticationforSession(_ challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
     completionHandler:   (Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        }
   ```

error: "Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape"

Also, handleChallenge method from AuthHandler class (which is a part of obj-c framework) looks like following.

```
-(BOOL)handleChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
                       completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,
                                                   NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler;
```

So basically I am stuck in a deadlock while I use Alamofire's closure syntax to delegate the auth challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the missing piece of your question is whether the completion handler in `Authhandler.handleChallenge` is escaping. It is, right?

But the `taskDidReceiveChallengeWithCompletion` completionHandler is non-escaping. So you're trying to figure out how to let it escape when it's not allowed to escape.

Looking at the Alamofire source code, about 3 months ago, they changed that completionHandler to be @escaping! See here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/b03b43cc381ec02eb9855085427186ef89055eef

You need to update to a version of Alamofire after that PR got merged or you need to figure out how to handle the completionHandler in a fully non-escaping way. Meaning, your `Authhandler.handleChallenge` can't have an escaped completionHandler.